# Java Script iframe src change links by order instead of random

Tags: javascript

I am trying change `iframe` src automatically with java script. But it's works in randomly. I want this works on by order and also change milliseconds to minutes..!

```
var pages=new Array();
pages[0]="http://www.virtusa.com";
pages[1]="https://www.listertechnologies.com/";
pages[2]="https://intellectdesign.com/";
var time=600000; // this is set in milliseconds
function pageChange() {
var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*pages.length);
document.getElementById("frame").src=pages[rand];
setTimeout("pageChange()",time);
}
onload=pageChange;
```

Comment: You want it to work on order but you are using `Math.random`. And 600000 miliseconds is equal to 10 minutes, no need for any explicit conversion.

Comment: @matus dubrava how change `Math.random` into order.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pages = new Array();
pages[0] = "http://www.virtusa.com";
pages[1] = "https://www.listertechnologies.com/";
pages[2] = "https://intellectdesign.com/";
var index = 0;
var minute = 60000;
var time = 10 * minute; 
function pageChange() {
    var rand = pages[index];
    document.getElementById("frame").src = rand;
    setTimeout(pageChange, time);
    index = index == pages.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
}
onload = pageChange;
```

Comment: Updated check now :)

Comment: Ohh sorry minute is coming undefined I update my code this time It will definitely work :)

Comment: It is because of this ` setTimeout("pageChange()", time);`

Comment: Change this to `setTimeout(pageChange, time);`